# WPF Visual Studio-esque Interface

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

I am tasked with creating an end-user designer in WPF.

This must be somewhat similar to the Visual Studio designer, where I have controls on the left (say, buttons), a central area that supports dragging/dropping said controls, and a property grid.

Could anyone lend some advice on how to properly do this?

My major issue is it needs to be almost exactly like Visual Studio, in the sense it supports things like snap-lines for alignment, a grid, etc.

Is the Visual Studio visual editor embedded-able or do I have to roll my own?

Any advice from someone with experience here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at [this](http://mahapps.com/) library. It's a very solid toolkit that redesign the default styles of your control with the Metro style (based on windows8 /10), and also add some custom controls too. I'm using it in all my projected and i didn't find any bug at the moment, so i am pretty satisfied. The look of your application can be rendered very similar in this way to the look of visual studio

Comment: Good comment but doesn't answer my question about re-creating a mini-Visual Studio designer.  Not asking about styling my app Metro.

Comment: @Patrick You asked how you can do something and i answered you. There is no magic tool that give you what you want. You have to build your interface and with this tool you can make it look like visual studio.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the response.  The difficult part I am facing is having to implement the advanced parts of the designer, especially areas like controls "snapping to" each other based on drag-drop alignment on a WPF Canvas.  That's where things get really tricky.